# Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: sessionFactory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.quad.dao.RoleDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
```

My sessionFactory configuration in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml  is

```
<bean id="sessionFactory class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"><property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    <property name="hibernateProperties">    <props>    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>    </props>    </property>    </bean>
```

i am using sessionFactory in RoleDAOImpl

my full mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.entity" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quad.service" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring-security.xml" />  --> 

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
      <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
      <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
      <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
 </bean>  

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
      <property name="hibernateProperties">  
       <props>  
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>      
       </props>  
      </property>  
</bean>
```

please help .

Comment: Do you have any other Spring configuration files?

Comment: @geoand spring security in resources folder

Comment: Maybe RoleDAOImpl class isn’t annotated with @Repository

Comment: fiskerXO RoleDAOImpl is annotated with @Repository

Comment: Does it say anything to you: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;` ?

Comment: Could you post the full mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml as well as web.xml?

Comment: Put hibernate on your classpath.

Comment: which version hibernate you have in your classpath?

Comment: Perhaps you have Hibernate 4 on your classpath, but you are using Hibernate 3 integration in the Spring configuration

Comment: Please add the full stack trace. If you use maven do a `mvn dependency:tree` to see if you have conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a problem with mismatched dependency versions.

org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider  was removed in Hibernate 4 (a different caching standard was created)

Your session factory class specified is:
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

which is specific to Hibernate 3.

This implies you're using hibernate 4 related dependencies with the wrong session factory class.

As long as you're using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE or higher, the hibernate 4 classes are available in spring-orm (as are the hibernate3 versions).

You have two options then:

1. Change back to Hibernate 3
  - This depends on how your project is built.
  - If it's using Maven, this would involve changing the hibernate-core dependencies
2. Change your spring configuration to Hibernate 4
  - This will only work for Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE or higher
  - For this change the above mentioned AnnotationSessionFactoryBean to:
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are injecting sessionFactory you must provide its setter and getter methods. it will resolve your problem